# Efficient outer product in python

Tags: python, numpy, multiplication

Outer product in python seems quite slow when we have to deal with vectors of dimension of order 10k.  Could someone please give me some idea how could I speed up this operation in python?

Code is as follows:

```
 In [8]: a.shape
 Out[8]: (128,)

 In [9]: b.shape
 Out[9]: (32000,)

 In [10]: %timeit np.outer(b,a)
 100 loops, best of 3: 15.4 ms per loop
```

Since I have to do this operation several times, my code is getting slower.

Comment: Show us your existing code.

Comment: If calling a single, typically highly optimized, numpy function is too slow, reconsider whether you can avoid calculating a full outer product. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: parallelize the calculations? here an example (a bit old though) http://atbrox.com/2010/02/08/parallel-machine-learning-for-hadoopmapreduce-a-python-example/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't really get any faster than that, these are your options:

**numpy.outer**

```
>>> %timeit np.outer(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.79 ms per loop
```

**numpy.einsum**

```
>>> %timeit np.einsum('i,j->ij', a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ms per loop
```

**numba**

```
from numba.decorators import autojit

@autojit
def outer_numba(a, b):
    m = a.shape[0]
    n = b.shape[0]
    result = np.empty((m, n), dtype=np.float)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            result[i, j] = a[i]*b[j]
    return result

>>> %timeit outer_numba(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.77 ms per loop
```

**parakeet**

```
from parakeet import jit

@jit
def outer_parakeet(a, b):
   ... same as numba

>>> %timeit outer_parakeet(a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop
```

**cython**

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
cimport cython
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def outer_cython(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] a, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] b):
    cdef int m = a.shape[0]
    cdef int n = b.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] result = np.empty((m, n), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            result[i, j] = a[i]*b[j]
    return result

>>> %timeit outer_cython(a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
```

**theano**

```
from theano import tensor as T
from theano import function

x = T.vector()
y = T.vector()

outer_theano = function([x, y], T.outer(x, y))

>>> %timeit outer_theano(a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.4 ms per loop
```

**pypy**

```
# Same code as the `outer_numba` function
>>> timeit.timeit("outer_pypy(a,b)", number=100, setup="import numpy as np;a = np.random.rand(128,);b = np.random.rand(32000,);from test import outer_pypy;outer_pypy(a,b)")*1000 / 100.0
16.36 # ms
```

### **Conclusions:**

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║  method   ║ time(ms)* ║ version ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ numba     ║ 9.77      ║ 0.16.0  ║
║ np.outer  ║ 9.79      ║ 1.9.1   ║
║ cython    ║ 10.1      ║ 0.21.2  ║
║ parakeet  ║ 11.6      ║ 0.23.2  ║
║ pypy      ║ 16.36     ║ 2.4.0   ║
║ np.einsum ║ 16.6      ║ 1.9.1   ║
║ theano    ║ 17.4      ║ 0.6.0   ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
* less time = faster
```

Comment: I like the explanation "less time = faster" :)

Comment: There's another method - broadcasting: `b[:,None]*a`.  But its timing is the same ballpark as the others, somewhere between `outer` and `einsum`.  The relative rankings vary some with the size of the 2 arrays.

Comment: In the numba version you should use ```float64``` instead of ```float```, otherwise it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 6):

@elyase's answer is great, and rightly accepted.  Here's an additional suggestion that, if you can use it, might make the call to `np.outer` even faster.

You say "I have to do this operation several times", so it is possible that you can reuse the array that holds the outer product, instead of allocating a new one each time.  That can give a nice boost in performance.

First, some random data to work with:

```
In [32]: a = np.random.randn(128)

In [33]: b = np.random.randn(32000)
```

Here's the baseline timing for np.outer(a, b) on my computer:

```
In [34]: %timeit np.outer(a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.52 ms per loop
```

Suppose we're going to repeat that operation several times, with arrays of the same shape.  Create an `out` array to hold the result:

```
In [35]: out = np.empty((128, 32000))
```

Now use `out` as the third argument of `np.outer`:

```
In [36]: %timeit np.outer(a, b, out)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop
```

So you get a nice performance boost if you can reuse the array that holds the outer product.

You get a similar benefit if you use the `out` argument of `einsum`, and in the cython function if you add a third argument for the output instead of allocating it in the function with `np.empty`.  (The other compiled/jitted codes in @elyase's answer will probably benefit from this, too, but I only tried the cython version.)

*Nota bene!* The benefit shown above might not be realized in practice.  The `out` array fits in the L3 cache of my CPU, and when it is used in the loop performed by the `timeit` command, it likely remains in the cache.  In practice, the array might be moved out of the cache between calls to `np.outer`.  In that case, the improvement isn't so dramatic, but it should still be at least the cost of a call to `np.empty()`, i.e.

```
In [53]: %timeit np.empty((128, 32000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop
```

Comment: Which version of python does this support third argument. For me, it is not supporting third argument out. *TypeError: outer() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
 *

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as using [`numpy.outer()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html): a single function call which will be implemented in C for high performance.