# Matlab to Python code conversion: Matrices are not aligned

Tags: python, numpy

Below is a sample code of MATLAB and its eqv Python code using Numpy package. The MATLAB code works fine but the Python code is giving issues:

MATLAB/OCTAVE

```
N=1200
YDFA_P0 = double([1;2;3;4;5])
P0=YDFA_P0 *ones(1, N)


octave:27> whos P0
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        P0          5x1200                   48000  double

Total is 6000 elements using 48000 bytes
```

Python

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
N=1200
YDFA_P0 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
P0 = np.dot(YDFA_P0, np.ones((1, N)))
P0 = YDFA_P0 * np.ones((1, N))
```

I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 5, in <module>
    P0 = np.dot(YDFA_P0, np.ones((1, N)))
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

How can I fix this error or rather port the Matlab code successfully to Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`, you are creating a matrix with one *row* (actually, it's just a one-dimensional vector), while `double([1;2;3;4;5])` is a matrix with one *column*. Try this:

```
In [14]: YDFA_P0 = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
In [15]: np.dot(YDFA_P0, np.ones((1,5)) )
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]])
```

Alternatively, you could also do `np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]]).transpose()` (note the `[[ ]]`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [outer product](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
>>> P0 = np.outer(YDFA_P0, np.ones(N))
>>> P0.shape
(5, 1200)
```

Comment: Outer product using ```numpy.einsum```: ```np.einsum('i,j->ij',YDFA_P0, np.ones(N))```

Comment: Yes also possible, `outer` [is slightly faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809511/efficient-outer-product-in-python/27809902#27809902)

Comment: Concur, just timed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.newaxis` to align the *first* array:

```
import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = a[:, np.newaxis]
>>> print b
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]]
>>> c = np.ones((1,5))
>>> print c
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
>>> np.dot(b, c)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]])
>>>
```