# Matlab to Python : why we are getting the error

Tags: python, numpy

It works in MATLAB / OCTAVE - how can I rightly fix it in Python:

```
octave:40> whos YDFA_ale_ase
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name              Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====              ====                     =====  ===== 
        YDFA_ale_ase     51x1                        408  double

Total is 51 elements using 408 bytes

octave:41> whos N1
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        N1          1x1200                    9600  double

Total is 1200 elements using 9600 bytes

octave:45> YDFA_ale_ase * N1
ans =

 Columns 1 through 20:

   46.8270   46.8270   46.8270 
..........................
```

But in Python I get  the below error:

```
np.dot(YDFA_ale_ase, 1.-N1)-np.dot(YDFA_ala_ase, N1)

ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

Other attempt:

```
YDFA_ale_ase* 1.-N1-YDFA_ala_ase* N1

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (51) (1,1200)
```

However :

```
print YDFA_ale_ase.shape, N1.shape
```

Gives me

```
(51,) (1, 1200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the shape of your arrays.  Keep in mind that Matlab matrices have at least 2 dims, while NUMPY can be 1 or even 0.  Most likely you are trying to `dot` a `(n,)` with a `(1,m)`.  Add a dimension on thr right of your `( n,)` array.   `Y[:, None]` is the easiest way.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users)

Comment: Thanks I have update the question with requested information - please let me know how to fix it then

Comment: in your case np.dot(YDFA_ale_ase[:,None], 1.-N1)-np.dot(YDFA_ala_ase[:,None], N1)

Comment: Thanks it resolved the issue. Is there a documentation where by I learn the migration rules with great examples

Comment: Other answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839769/matlab-to-python-code-conversion-matrices-are-not-aligned