# Numpy multiply arrays into matrix (outer product)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have 2 numpy arrays of shape (5,1) say:
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[2,4,2,3,6]

How can I make a matrix multiplying each i-th element with each j-th? Like:

```
..a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b 
2    2, 4, 6, 8,10
4    4, 8,12,16,20
2    2, 4, 6, 8,10
3    3, 6, 9,12,15
6    6,12,18,24,30
```

Without using forloops? is there any combination of reshape, reductions or multiplications that I can use?

Right now I create a a*b tiling of each array along rows and along colums and then multiply element wise, but it seems to me there must be an easier way.

Comment: You want the outer product of the two arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809511/efficient-outer-product-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [numpy.outer()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) and [numpy.transpose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) routines:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,4,2,3,6]
c = np.outer(a,b).transpose()

print(c)
```

---

Or just with swapped array order:

```
c = np.outer(b, a)
```

---

The output;

```
[[ 2  4  6  8 10]
 [ 4  8 12 16 20]
 [ 2  4  6  8 10]
 [ 3  6  9 12 15]
 [ 6 12 18 24 30]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. If you have any suggestions to make the question more understandable please let me know. I forgot this was called the outer product fo vectors.

Comment: @ZloySmiertniy, welcome, I would add *(outer product)* at the end of the title + formatting code

Answer (score 2):

For some reason `np.multiply.outer` seems to be faster than `np.outer` for small inputs.  And broadcasting is faster still - but for bigger arrays they are all pretty much equal.

```
%timeit np.outer(a,b)
%timeit np.multiply.outer(a,b)
%timeit a[:, None]*b

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.97 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.27 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 µs per loop

a = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
b = np.random.randint(0,10,100)

%timeit np.outer(a,b)
%timeit np.multiply.outer(a,b)
%timeit a[:, None]*b

100000 loops, best of 3: 15.5 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 14 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 µs per loop

a = np.random.randint(0,10,10000)
b = np.random.randint(0,10,10000)

%timeit np.outer(a,b)
%timeit np.multiply.outer(a,b)
%timeit a[:, None]*b

10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 152 ms per loop
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. The matrices I am working with are very big, like 90K times 100k elements so maybe it will not have any change