# numpy - einsum vs naive implementation runtime performaned

Tags: python, performance, numpy, dot

I have a two dimensional array Y of size (N,M), say for instance:

```
N, M = 200, 100
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,(N,M))
```

For each N, I want to compute the dot product of the vector (M,1) with its transpose, which returns a (M,M) matrix. One way to do it inefficiently is:

```
Y = Y[:,:,np.newaxis]
[Y[i,:,:] @ Y[i,:,:].T for i in range(N)]
```

which is quite slow: timeit on the second line returns

```
11.7 ms ± 1.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I thought a much better way to do it is the use the einsum numpy function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
np.einsum('ijk,imk->ijm', Y, Y, optimize=True)
```

(which means: for each row i, create a (j,k) matrix where its elements results from the dot product on the last dimension m)

The two methods does returns the exact same result, but the runtime of this new version is disappointing (only a bit more than twice the speed)

```
3.82 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

One would expect much more improvement by using the vectorized einsum function since the first method is **very** inefficient... Do you have an explanation for this ? Does there exists a better way to do this calculation ?

Comment: There's no sum reduction happening. Don't expect einsum to help. You can simply do : `Y*Y[:,None,:,0]`.

Comment: There is not much speedup possible (only about a factor of 2x with eg. an efficient Numba implementation). The reason for this is that this calculation is completely memory-bandwidth limited. If you do some reduction (eg. sum) afterwards there is easily an order of magnitude or more possible. An example to optimize the reduction case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58189944/4045774

Answer (score 1):

```
In [60]: N, M = 200, 100 
    ...: Y = np.random.normal(0,1,(N,M))                                                                             
In [61]: Y1 = Y[:,:,None]
```

Your iteration, 200 steps to produce (100,100) arrays:

```
In [62]: timeit [Y1[i,:,:]@Y1[i,:,:].T for i in range(N)]                                                            
18.5 ms ± 784 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`einsum` only modestly faster:

```
In [64]: timeit np.einsum('ijk,imk->ijm', Y1,Y1)                                                                     
14.5 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

but you could apply the `@` in full 'batch' mode with:

```
In [65]: timeit Y[:,:,None]@Y[:,None,:]                                                                              
7.63 ms ± 224 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

But as Divakar notes, the sum axis is size 1, so you could use plain broadcasted multiply.  This is an outer product, not a matrix one.

```
In [66]: timeit Y[:,:,None]*Y[:,None,:]                                                                              
8.2 ms ± 64.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

'vectorizing' gives big gains when doing many iterations on a simple operation.  For fewer operations on a more complex operation, the gain isn't as great.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer ! What kind of options do I have in order to make it as fast as possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, yet covers the subject in many details: [efficient outer product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809511/efficient-outer-product-in-python).

In particular if you are interested in adding numba dependency, that may be your fastest option.

Updating part of numba code from the original post and adding the multi outer product:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from numba.typed import List

@jit(nopython=True)
def outer_numba(a, b):
    m = a.shape[0]
    n = b.shape[0]
    result = np.empty((m, n))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            result[i, j] = a[i]*b[j]
    return result

@jit(nopython=True)
def multi_outer_numba(Y):

    all_result = List()
    for k in range(Y.shape[0]):
        y = Y[k]           
        n = y.shape[0]
        tmp_res = np.empty((n, n))
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                tmp_res[i, j] = y[i]*y[j]
        all_result.append(tmp_res)

    return all_result

r = [outer_numba(Y[i],Y[i]) for i in range(N)]
r = multi_outer_numba(Y)
```